# Problem with building applications

Tags: objective-c, building

I am currently running Mac OS 10.6.2, with Xcode 3.2.1.
When I try to build any application, at all, I get this error:

`"No object for "com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.CarbonFramework" key."`

I just installed Xcode, upgrading from 2.2.1, and got this error upon making a new application and trying to build.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you emailed the Xcode-users list?  Several of the Xcode development team monitor that list.
[Apple Mailing Lists](http://lists.apple.com)